# PHPWord. Ошибок нет, как и замены

Tags: php, phpword

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
//подключаем PHPWord
require_once 'PHPWord.php';
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

//выбираем файл для работы
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('test.docx');

//изменим его
$document->setValue('Value1', '123');
$document->save('test1.docx');
```

Ест-но в файле я прописал ${Value1}. Никаких ошибок. В новом файле - нет замены. Может кто про диагностировать? (ест-но PHPWord на хостинге и примеры из example работают)

Comment: Вот тут есть решение http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/372641/phpword-template-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-setvalue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никаких ошибок и не будет, если класс не найдет шаблон для замены.
Откройте файл test.docx архиватором, посмотрите в структуру файла word/document.xml, там где зашит шаблон, должно быть что-то типа:

```
<w:r>
     <w:t>
          ${Value1}
     </w:t>
</w:r>
```

Если шаблон "${Value1}" символ в символ не соответствует, замены не произойдет.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @mixalef, а что там вставилось вместо "${Value1}"?

Answer (score 1):

[DocXGen](https://github.com/psinetron/DocXGen) Попробуй это решение. Бесплатное и решает проблему, когда Value было записано не с первого раза. Например если сначала в ворде ввести {} а потом уже в эти фигурные скобки ввести Value1, то значение не заменится, потому что структура XML будет примерно такая:

```
<w:r>
     <w:t>
          {
     </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
     <w:t>
          Value1
     </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
     <w:t>
          }
     </w:t>
</w:r>
```