# PHPWord Template: не всегда работает setValue

Tags: php, шаблоны, phpword

Написал по примерам:

```
$fileName = './protected/data/template.docx';
$word = new PHPWord();
$word = $word->loadTemplate($fileName);
$word->setValue('post', '123');

$h2d_file_uri = tempnam('', 'htd');
$word->save($h2d_file_uri);
```

В документе вставил текст и **`${post}`**.
Не всегда заменяется этот post на нужное мне значение. И заметил, что если template.docx открыть в WordPad и сохранить (при этом он скажет, что некоторые данные docx потеряются, т.к. не все поддерживается), то после этого post заменяется.

В чем дело, как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменил у самой библиотеки функцию setValue, проблема вроде решилась:

```
public function setValue($search, $replace) {
    if(substr($search, 0, 2) !== '${' && substr($search, -1) !== '}') {
        //было - $search = '${'.$search.'}';
        $search = '/\$\{.*?'.$search.'.*?\}/is';
    }

    if(!is_array($replace)) {
        //$replace = utf8_encode($replace);
    }

    //было - $this->_documentXML = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->_documentXML);
    $this->_documentXML = preg_replace($search, $replace, $this->_documentXML);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

При сохранении файла в формат *.doc Word может заменить (не обязательно) ваши `${post}`. Лучше сделать всё в два шага:

1. В Word'e вставить в нужные места нужные значения `${post}`
2. Сохранить документ в формат XML-документ Word. Открыть его в
   текстовом редакторе (Notepad++, PHPStorm), сделать поиск по своим
   `${post}`. Скорее всего, они будут разнесены примерно так:

   ```
   <w:r>
        <w:t>
             {
        </w:t>
   </w:r>
   <w:r>
        <w:t>
             Value1
        </w:t>
   </w:r>
   <w:r>
        <w:t>
             }
        </w:t>
   </w:r>
   ```

   Нужно перенести всё в один `<w:r>${post}</w:r>`, лучше если в `<w:r>`
   будут какие-то данные: `<w:r w:rsidRPr="00BF6D1A">`, а остатки
   удалить.